# Check for editable column in a table with jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

In the table the first column is editable and after edit it/change it I want to show the alert as Changed. I am calling the check function after 5000ms.

***Adding Code Snippet for My code***

Something I missed or wrong somewhere. Please Help.

Here is the Code.

```js
  var table = $("table tbody");

    table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            id = $tds.eq(0).text(),
            product = $tds.eq(1).text();
        $check = function() {
         if(($tds.eq(0).text() != id) && ($tds.eq(1).text() != product)){
            alert("Changed");
        }
        else{
            alert("Not changed");
        }
           
    }
    setInterval(function() { $check(); }, 5000);
        
        alert(id + ":" + product);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td contentEditable>63</td>
            <td>Computer</td>
               
        </tr>
       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(($tds.eq(0).text() != id) && ($tds.eq(1).text() != product)){
```

This only triggers when both fields changed, change it to a "||"

Also check out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input for capturing contenteditable changes.

Comment: you also may want to update your product parameter within the "changed" block or you will keep getting the changed block executing every 5 seconds even if nothing more has changed.